# Add-PnPPageWebPart: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, error, pnp-powershell, pnp

I'm trying to add Quick Links to my SharePoint site using the PnP Module. However, when trying to run the command:

```
Add-PnPPageWebPart -Page $page -DefaultWebPartType "QuickLinks" -Section 2 -Column 1
```

I get the error:

> Add-PnPPageWebPart: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I tried multiple things, I even get the error when trying to run the examples from: https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Add-PnPPageWebPart.html

I tried creating the section manually and running examples

Comment: What are the rest of the script? The error suggest that the your variable $page don't refer to a valid page-object.

Comment: hey, my $page is: "/sites/Testhome/SitePages/Home.aspx", also tried different forms since i became desperate.

Comment: According to the documentation, you are supposed to just set the parameter to the actual page name - so "Home" should work.

https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Add-PnPPageWebPart.html